# How, send Form title (Contact form 7 - WP Plugin) in hidden input?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Its possible send contatc form name in email body?

[contact-form-7 id="86" title="**Contact form 1**"]

I try the Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension — WordPress Plugins, but my form are in modal items, when i click in one, show me the modal, and change the url (add -> ?id=23) but the Dynamic Text Extension only accept this field in reload page not after.

Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar with the hidden input field and custom shortcode in functions.php. This might helps too

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('hidden', 'wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler', true);

function wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler($tag) {
    if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

    $name = $tag['name'];
    if (empty($name)) return '';

    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
   return $html;
}
```

Then add custom tag in contact form 7

```
[hidden pageTitle]
```

In email settings

```
Page title is: [pageTitle]
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks, but in my page i have, for exemple, 5 modals and each modal have one form. if i click in one button, open one modal. the page name can not distinct the form. no have possiblity to add title of form like this Modal1->[contact-form-7 id="86" title="modal1"] Modal2->[contact-form-7 id="86" title="modal2"]. thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, there are many ways how to do it. F.e.: Contact form 7 has special function wpcf7_get_current_contact_form() to get current form object. To get title/name/id just call f.e. $form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form(); $form->title(); Then you can store the title in hidden field to keep the preference

Comment: works, but dont write title of shortcut [contact-form-7 id="86" title="title of shortcut"], this write the title of backoffice :(

Answer (score 2):

You can just use cf7 plugin [features](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/):

Add hidden field in form template, like `[hidden title default:shortcode_attr]`

Then use this field `[title]` in the mail body.

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party (as always) but I also needed to differentiate between instances of the same form. By scouring Stackoverflow and the source code I came up with a solution:

Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'cf7_add_form_title' );
function cf7_add_form_title() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'form_title', 'cf7_add_form_title_handler' );
}
function cf7_add_form_title_handler( $tag ) {
    $form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form();
    return $form->shortcode_attr('title');
}
```

As a hidden form field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="[form_title]"/>
```

And as an email-tag:

```
[title]
```

The name can of course be anything.